# NAS: System.IO.IOException: Insufficient system resources exists to complete the requested service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have a console app. (C# written in VSCode) which is looking through files (>200000 at a time) and gather data out of them.
It is working without any problem if the source and destination folders are on the local computer. Also good if the source&destination are shared folders on another PC.
Problem occurs when I set the source&destination to point to a NAS (shared folder).

I am thinking it is a memory issue, but how could I be sure out of this error message:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
> Corporation.  All rights reserved.   Unhandled exception.
> System.IO.IOException: Insufficient system resources exist to complete
> the requested service. :
> 'W:\2020-08\2020-08-18\ID_GEBER_NG21_BOT\VC52034208097F01BCS'    at
> System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateRelativeDirectoryHandle(ReadOnlySpan`1
> relativePath, String fullPath)    at
> System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)    at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1
> source)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1
> source)    at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String
> searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)    at
> ExtractMtagtoCSV.Program.Main() in C:\temp\ExtractMtagtoCSV - v2 -
> testovernetework\Program.cs:line 80

Content of "line 80":

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"W:\\2020-08","*.mtag", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The application using far less then 1GB according to the VScode's Process explorer, the NAS has 4GBs.

Anybody could help?

Comment: Please insert the error message into your question as text. This helps users who use the search function for similar errors.

Comment: It is there now

Comment: Two days ago you added more details of the problem but as an answer. On this site answers are for answering the question, not for adding more detail. As that not-an-answer has been deleted I am not sure whether you can see the comment I placed on it. I repeat the essence of that comment here: Please edit the question to add more details, or if necessary ask a new question. The code you showed in that deleted not-an-answer seems very different to that in the original question so perhaps it should be a new question. Additionally, you say it crashes but you have not stated what error is produced.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that there are simply too many files in that shared folder. The assignment

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"W:\2020-08","*.mtag", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

is finding all the files in all the subdirectories and saving their names into the array as explained in the documentation of [GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1). That page suggests that you should instead use the [EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-3.1) method and not assign the results to an array, but process them via an iterator.

Comment: Hi, having the same failure with the EnumerateFiles method

Comment: @UrPocok : So update the question, or perhaps write a new question, and show your new code.